# Image is multiplied three times in OpenCV, what causes this?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have one gray scale image which is just the R channel of a photo, now I'm trying to write that R channel into a new image, which is an RGB image. Ideally, the new image would look just like the old image, but red.

What happens though is that in the new image, the old image appears three times squished next to each other.

Here you can see the gray scale image and the output image.

[image: Input image]
[image: Output image]

Here is my code, I think it's pretty straightforward:

```
  Mat img_in = imread("in.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
  Mat img_out = Mat::zeros(img_in.size(), CV_8UC3);
  for (int i = 0; i < img_in.rows; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < img_in.cols; j++)
    {
      img_out.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[2] = img_in.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[2];
    }
  }
  imwrite("test_img_in.png", img_in);
  imwrite("test_img_out.png", img_out);
```

At first I thought it was some kind of indices mixup, but I've tried a lot of combinations, and it always multiplies the output image three times horizontally, never vertically.

Now my thought is that it comes from some OpenCV specification, like the `CV_8UC3` type (I've tried others too), which I've chosen because I think it support RGB images. Unfortunately, I don't know too much about OpenCV itself, that's why I'm seeking help here.

PS: This is part of a whole bigger program which wants to generate a color image from three gray scale channel images, but I'm currently stuck on combining the aligned gray scale images, since this happens. The code I posted is isolated from the rest of the program and works like this on its own.
My OpenCV version is 2.4.11.

Comment: Kinda besides the point, but this algorithm looks like it will be really slow. Why not use [merge](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#void%20merge%28const%20Mat*%20mv,%20size_t%20count,%20OutputArray%20dst%29) or [mixChannels](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#void%20mixChannels%28const%20Mat*%20src,%20size_t%20nsrcs,%20Mat*%20dst,%20size_t%20ndsts,%20const%20int*%20fromTo,%20size_t%20npairs%29) instead? Or convert and blank the B and G colour planes.

Comment: However, this seems like there's perhaps an issue on loading. Can you show that part of code?

Comment: try = img_in.at<unsigned char>(i,j) instead

Comment: @DanMašek I can't use `merge` because the other channel images have different sizes. I added the loading code part, and I will try the suggestions now, thanks so far @Micka

Comment: @CGuy Ok, now it's obvious, as DimChtz explains. In general, I would avoid this kind of per-pixel algorithm. The functions provided by the library tend to be well optimized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
img_out.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[2] = img_in.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[2];
```

As you said the input image is gray. So, just use:

```
img_out.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[2] = img_in.at<unsigned char>(i,j);
```

Comment: Thank you @DimChtz, this solved my issue. I assume gray scale images just don't have the `Vec3b` array, which makes sense.

Comment: @CGuy Exactly, they have one channel.

Answer (score 1):

you will get the same result by loading your image as 3 channel and subtract `Scalar(255,255,0)`

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Mat src = imread(argv[1]);
    imshow("src", src );
    src -= Scalar(255,255,0);
    imshow("Red channel", src );
    waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```